# how to copy windowshare files in linux system?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, unix, archlinux

Hi I am new to Linux system. I need to copy files from "connect to server" windowshare as smb files location to local linux path. I tried this but i can't work properly, How to copy files from smb://crystal/share.

I tried:

```
find smb://crystal/share/ -type f -exec scp {} /var/www/share/
```

it can work with local system but I need simply copy from windowshare files, local server files,

I can connect to server option in linux, it option can be copy files manually but I like to copy files by terminal, any one help me....

Thanks advanced...

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `mount` the remote filesystem first:

```
sudo mount -t cifs '//HOST/DIR' /LOCAL/DIR -o user=<WINDOWS_USER>,iocharset=utf8
```

Then you can `find` and copy files.

Comment: thanks @Alexander L. Belikoff... can you please give with sample beacuse i trying i newly so please,... make with example

Comment: The sample is in the answer: mount the server dir the way described after which you can use /LOCAL/DIR as if it's a local file tree.

Comment: oh k k thank u very much!!! "user=<WINDOWS_USER>" why we using this? is it default syntax?

Comment: You have to specify the user on the remote (server, SMB) side. If the username is the same, you can skip it  it depends on the way authentication is configured between these two machines.

Comment: Hi alex!! Can i ask one more doubts!! I trying files copy from server side linux and windows to local system it also optional. Exactly I need auto backup!! if any idea please ...

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you try to re-phrase it?

Comment: I have copy files from linux or window server to my local unix or linux system. so it called Auto backup process, Please let me know if it any idea for this process. becuase I have just idea only.. I don't know how can start this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what this process is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the smb file system, first, so that it looks "native" to the unix tools.

See:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html